# Sending Password Safe files per unencrypted mail secure enough?

Tags: email, passwords, encryption

I use Password Safe with portable key files ( http://passwordsafe.sourceforge.net/ ) for storing my passwords. Unfortunately, I've forgotten the files at home today and right now I need one of the passwords I can't remember.

Is it safe to send portable PWSafe files per mail?

Comment: double up by putting it inside a password protected zip file with a strong password.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I couldn't find the encryption scheme PWSafe uses on their site, but it's safe to assume it's not a trivial one.

Usually with these systems, the weak link is your password. So if your password is not prone to simple attacks (i.e., you're not using your name, or Space Balls' 12345, or anything that won't survive a simple dictionary or brute force attack) I would say it's safe to send it via email.

Comment: [Twofish, apparently.](http://www.schneier.com/passsafe.html) Program designed by Schneier himself, should be good enough :D

Comment: If that's the case, then it's safe enough - again, with the key phrase caveat.

Comment: OK thx
I know I'm a bit late but thanks anyway. I think my password is safe enough.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a tool like NoteShred and simply attach the PWSafe files to a note, which will be encrypted on the server.
You then simply download the attachment from your other computer, which will destroy the note and attachment afterwards, and you'll never need to email the file or transfer it over an un-encrypted connection.

Same goes for just sending text messages or "notes" to people.  Create a note, then send them the link.  Transfer them the password over messenger to decrypt the note.

**https://www.noteshred.com**